# How Django find correct Template variable from TemplateView

Tags: python, django

I have this pieces of code:

```
# newspaper_project/urls.py

from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView

urlpatterns = [
    path('', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='home.html'), name='home'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('users/', include('users.urls'))
    path('users/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
]
```

```
# users/urls.py
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('signup/', views.SignUp.as_view(), name='signup'),
]
```

```
# users/views.py
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.views import generic
from .forms import CustomUserCreationForm

    class SignUp(generic.CreateView):
        form_class = CustomUserCreationForm
        success_url = reverse_lazy('login')
        template_name = 'signup.html'
```

```
<!-- templates/home.html -->
{% block title %}Home{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        Hi {{ user.username }}!
        <p><a href="{% url 'logout' %}">logout</a></p>
    {% else %}
        <p>You are not logged in</p>
        <a href="{% url 'login' %}">login</a> |
        <a href="{% url 'signup' %}">signup</a>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

And my question is:
How Django know what model is used in home.html template? (how Django know about "username"?)

In TemplateView i don't specify Model (in this case CustomUser). When we want to access and render database data, we need specify Model class (or in this case Form) in view. And from here Django accesses for template variable. Isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `TEMPLATES` setting, you have the [auth context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/api/#django-contrib-auth-context-processors-auth) enabled.

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

This adds `user` (the currently logged-in user or an anonymous user if not logged in) and `perms` (which stores the user's permissions) to the template context.

Answer (score 0):

To setup a URL by doing `path('', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='home.html'), name='home')` is just about the simplest way to configure a view.

You wouldn't really do anything complicated with that, but you can specify some context variables using [extra_context](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/class-based-views/mixins-simple/#django.views.generic.base.ContextMixin.extra_context), for example;

```
path(
    '',
    TemplateView.as_view(
        template_name='home.html',
        extra_context={
            'page_title': 'Home Page',
        }
    ),
    name='home'
)
```

To keep the `urls.py` clean you'd likely create another view for your home page and add your context variables that way;

```
class HomePageView(TemplateView):

    template_name = "home.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['page_title'] = 'Home Page'
        context['user'] = CustomUser.objects.first()  # Filter for user here
        return context
```

```
<!-- templates/home.html -->
{% block title %}{{ page_title }}{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
        Hi {{ request.user.username }}!

        The user you were interested in is {{ user.username }}

        <p><a href="{% url 'logout' %}">logout</a></p>
    {% else %}
        <p>You are not logged in</p>
        <a href="{% url 'login' %}">login</a> |
        <a href="{% url 'signup' %}">signup</a>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

You can access the logged in user from the request object like this providing you have the request context processor in your settings;

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                ...
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                ...
            ],
        },
    },
]
```